# Same domain name as an old site

Tags: internet, trademark, domain-name

A few years ago I was looking for a domain name to use for my website. After trying a couple hundred names I eventually found one that wasn't taken. I did a quick google to make sure the name wasn't trademarked or tied to any businesses.

Not long ago I found a post on a forum from almost 10 years ago where the person posted a link to their hobby website which happened to have the same domain name.

Am I in the wrong, or could face any legal action from any earnings made form the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question lacks some details. So you registered a domain name, and later find someone else used that domain name (in the past) for a hobby website?

Then no, you don't need to worry about it.

If that person has a current trademark on the name used in the domain name, and your website provides/sells products or services in the same area, then you could have a problem. But that doesn't sound like it's the issue.